# how to customize export data(listview) SuiteCRM

Tags: suitecrm

I am able to customize if i write create_export_query() in main modules(modules/Leads/lead.php)

but I want this should be upgrade safe code,

can we add create_export_query() method in custom path instead of in lead.php

if so in which file we can add this function other than main module location?

custom/modules/Leads/lead.php will work?

thanks
Naren

Answer (score 0):

custom/modules/Leads/lead.php will not work until you change beanFile location into main bean.

There are 2 ways to do this.

```
1) Make an extension, custom/Extension/application/Ext/Include, make
a new file CustomLeads.php, put your custom BeanFile location here
for lead module.

2) As export is certainly an action,you may create a custom
controller,ie custom/modules/Leads/controller.php, create a new
function action_export, put your custom code there.
```

Overriding bean of Suite core module is not recommeneded as it may crack whole system at any point. You should go with #2.